# Any working TryParse or IsNumeric with suffix U u L l UL Ul uL ul LU Lu lU lu .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, integer, literals

how can I check if a string value is a number or not it seems to keep failing because it has a suffix attached to it.

This is what i mean by suffix
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx

```
Dim value As String = "4294967295U"

If IsNumeric(value) Then
    MsgBox "is number"
End If

Dim val as UInteger
If UInteger.TryParse(value, num) Then
    MsgBox "is number also"
End If
```

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the `U` bit? `"4294967295U".TrimEnd('U')`.

Comment: @Asad I want to keep it all as a one liner, I could I guess but then I would need to make sure if its has a letter or not, I think I might go with casting it automatically to value but then again it may be a string.. but I want to avoid using Try/Catch as its' very slow

Comment: @Asad that's actually not to bad.. I think only `U's` are used and nothing else so I could do that

Comment: @Asad you should post that as the answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your input, you might be able to clean up any known prefixes/suffixes before doing the check. Looking at the single example you've provided, you can use `TrimEnd` to remove trailing `U`s.

```
Dim knownSuffixes = New Char() {"U"c}

If IsNumeric(value.TrimEnd(knownSuffixes)) Then
    MsgBox "is number"
End If
```

You should be careful about edge cases here. I don't know what kind of input you're looking for. Is, for example, `1234UUUUUU` invalid input? If so, this will give you false positives.

Another, perhaps more robust approach, is to use a regex that specifies exactly what sequence of characters is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Suffixes are used when you're declaring your numeric values as constants in the code - to let compiler know what type it should treat that number as. It's necessary because `1` could mean any of `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `byte`, and more.

When you're using `TryParse` it's not necessary, because class you're using to call `TryParse` on (`UInteger` in your case) already knows what type you expect the input to represent. So it should be just the number, without suffixes.

Comment: ya but those suffixes exist in a string format and I want to cast it down to a value so I can decide if it was a string or a number i'm trying to make like a router

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Asad for answer this works good

```
Dim value as String = "4294967295U"
value = value.TrimEnd(New Char() {"U", "u", "L", "l"})
If IsNumeric(value) Then
    'Yes is number now :)
Else
    'Boo!
End If
```

Can probably chain it with .ToLowerCase() or .ToUpperCase() to get it down to just 2 elements.

Comment: That code would fail to compile with `Option Strict On` and fail to work as expected for multi-character suffixes with `Option Strict off`.  In short, it's bad code.

Comment: Oh how can I allow multiple characters in a char array ?

Comment: You just need four characters in that array. `U`, `L`, `u` and `l`. I haven't used VB.NET in a while, so I'm not sure why you're allowed to add multi-character strings to an array of chars, but you don't need to.

Comment: You can't have multi-character `Char` values because a `Char` inherently represents a single character.  Also, by calling `Trim` with a `Char` array like `{"U"c, "u"c, "L"c, "l"c}`, you allow input like "123Lulu" to pass, which it obviously shouldn't.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was asking the opposite question. Why does that even compile? I've put this in Visual Studio and it seems to be perfectly happy with `new Char() { "U" }` (notice absence of `c` suffix), which doesn't seem right. Regarding `LuLU` etc, this depends on the OP's input. The robust way to do it is to have a custom parser, either by writing a state machine etc. or more reasonably by using a regex. However, in many cases you just need to sanitize input given certain assumptions, not verify all possible edge cases.

Comment: @Asad, that would only work with `Option Strict Off`.  With `Option Strict On`, the narrowing conversion from `String` to `Char` would fail.  With `Option Strict Off`, any mulit-character `String` would be converted to a `Char` for just the first character.